# How to combine two tables into one?

Tags: excel

This is what I want to do:

[image]

In previous work, I made some calculation and have the result (left part of the image) and now I want to use it somewhere else. The problem is that the value that I want to reuse is a combination. In my example, I have to reference both "No.8"'s `M` value and `V` value. I have to type `=C30` and `=C38` to reference them.

If there a way, having referenced the first one`=C30`, to reference the `V` relative to the `M`, something like `=C(30+8)` (because the relevant `V` is 8th down from `M`)?

Comment: Have you tried power query that might help. Just take a look at this link http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/using-power-query-to-combine-data-from-multiple-excel-files-into-one-table/

Comment: If you use helper column with concatenated values from Column A and B, you can use `Vlookup` or if you cannot alter the positions, `Index-Match` combination.

Comment: @L42 Quite complex, but solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. If you can post your solution that would be great. You can accept it and who knows someone might give you an upvote? :)

Answer (score 0):

With a couple of named ranges (say `arM` for A30:C37 and `arV` for A38:C45) and assuming the output array is labelled as shown, where shown, then in J34 copied across and down:

```
=VLOOKUP($H$34,INDIRECT("ar"&$I34),RIGHT(J$33)+1,0)
```